# Integrate Monaco Editor into LitElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, monaco-editor, lit-element

i try to crete a Code Playground in open-wc and would like to use Monaco Editor. the problem is, that i can't simply intregrate it. This is how i tried it and it works but the performance is horrible.

```
updated(changedProperties) {
    let container = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('container');
s
    function loadScript(filename, callback) {
      var fileref = document.createElement('script');
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      fileref.onload = callback;
      fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
      if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
      }
    }

    loadScript('../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js', function () {


      require.config({paths: {'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs'}});

      require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {

        var editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
          value: [
            'function x() {',
            '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
            '}'
          ].join('\n'),
          language: 'javascript'
        });
      });

    });

  }


  render() {
    return html`
              <h2> Monaco Editor Sample</h2>
      <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid grey"></div>

    `;
  }
```

Comment: This is just my opinion and I'm sure many would agree, but its good practice to avoid copious amounts of external dependencies because of potentially decreased performance and uncertainty of stability in production. A lot of frameworks that pop up are generally written by people who do not have a solid grasp on fundamentals and unknowingly write poorly optimized things.

Comment: Have you tried skipping the Lit layer and use a native Custom Element? I have seen it done years ago: https://github.com/paulvarache/monaco-editor-element

Comment: shouldn't it be firstUpdated instead of updated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Light Dom` to be able to use it.

You must add this to all parents

```
createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
}
```

> You must take into account that the styles will stop working and you must replace them with `<style>` inside `render()`